# Possible to have jqplot mouseover/highlight activate from legend as well as chart segments?

Tags: jqplot

Sometimes my segments are too small to be visible enough to click/mouseover. Is it possible to trigger the same mouseover on the chart by mousing over the associated legend?

My legend & custom highlighter code:

```
            legend: {
                renderer: $.jqplot.EnhancedLegendRenderer,
                show: true,
                location: 's',
                placement: 'insideGrid',
                rendererOptions: {
                    numberRows: 2
                }
            },
            highlighter: {
                show: true,
                tooltipLocation: 'sw',
                useAxesFormatters: false,
                tooltipAxes: 'y',
                yvalues: 3,
                formatString: '<table class="jqplot-highlighter">' +
                    '<tr><td>Impact:</td><td>%s</td></tr>' +
                    '<tr><td>Percentage:</td><td>%s</td></tr>' +
                    '<tr><td>Actual:</td><td>%s</td></tr></table>'
            }
```

Works beautifully, would just like to have it activate from the legend too if possible?

Comment: please provide more info like what kind of graph it is, do you want to activate all the mouseover of that series when you hover over the series legend. Please shar more info. thanks

Comment: It's a pie chart but I doubt that matters, which is why I didn't mention it?  Not sure though so apologies for missing that off. You can see what I'm already showing above, I just hoped there'd be something I could add to the "legend" bit above that would trigger the same thing shown in the highlighter bit.

Answer (score 0):

You could define your own event handler for .jqplot-table-legend-label or some other selector and then do whatever you need to in that.

Comment: Fair enough. Is there a specific place where custom event handlers are added to jqplot controls?  Any links to examples perhaps?

Comment: Just load the js file with your event handler like you load any other js file in your app.